# Windows 8 Task Manager Settings Reset to Default if Windows is not Shut Down Properly

Tags: windows-8, task-manager, default-settings

I liked the windows task manager in windows 8 because of the new features compared to the older versions.

I change its settings according to my needs:

- Always on top
- Set the update speed to fast (update twice per second)
- View task manager as more details (shows more information rather than only running apps)
- Show the CPU graphs (performance tab) in logical processors (one graph per CPU)

When my computer did not shut down properly for some reason (either power interruption, system crash, pressing and holding the ON button, etc.), boot my computer again and starting up the task manager, I noticed that the settings was restored to factory default and my desired settings are gone. It shows only running apps and I need to click the more details again. So, I need to change those settings again.

I do that again and again every time when my computer did not shut down properly.

Why is that happening? Is there a solution to avoid this in the next time that my PC did not shut down properly? Older task manager don't have that problem.

I've been searching for information everywhere and found nothing about it.

Comment: It would be better to work out **why** your computer is not shutting properly as this can have other possible (some serious) consequences.

Comment: The task manager application, like a few other small applications, may save its configuration on exit and then open the last configuration on the next startup. If there is no "Last Configuration" then it just opens the factory default. That's about all I can imagine

Comment: @DavidPostill That problem will happen each time the computer did not shut down properly for ALL reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Late reply, but I have been useing a workaround for that for the last couple of years.

As an overclocker, I am used to system frezes, crashes and BSODs. But I digress...

---

### The problem

In **Windows 8/8.1** Task Manager functions in a very odd manner.
Upon launch, it reads its settings from the *Windows Registry*, and then *erases the key value which stores them!* (This is also the reason for losing your configuration when taskmgr doesn't do a clean exit, i.e. system crash while it's open, or you kill the process.)

---

### The workaround

1. Run `taskmgr.exe`, then customize and configure it to your preference.
2. Then, close it **gracefully** (yes, via the `X` button).
3. Run (*Start+R*) `regedit.exe` and navigate to the following location:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TaskManager
   ```
4. If you see a key named `Preferences`, you are good to proceed to the next step:
5. *File* -> *Export* and make sure that you **only** export *Selected Branch* with the above location described. Select a convenient place to save the `.key` file.
6. Whenever you lose your Task Manager configuration for any reason, run the `.key` file and follow the prompt (press Yes) to import your last good state back.

   **N.B.** Make sure that Task Manager is closed when you do the import, otherwise it will just scrap your import and write its current config when you exit it.

---

### Tips & Tricks

#### I. Autorun on startup

1. Navigate to the following location:

   %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
2. Create a new file with a `.cmd` extension, for example `taskmgr.cmd`
3. Open the file with your favourite text editor - even Notepad will do the trick
4. Invoke the `.reg` export with it *absolute path:*

   ```
   regedit /s "X:\ABSOLUTE\PATH\TO\FILE\file.reg"
   ```

**Consider** that this will always revert your task manager config to the one you initially made, so you will have to keep the `.reg` file update with any changes you want to keep.

Comment: I'm still clinging to Windows 7 like some kind of luddite, but just in case anyone else is too, I'd like to point out that the reg path on Windows 7 was "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\TaskManager".  Note the "NT" suffix in the middle there. Not sure if this was a typo or a difference post-7.